# Ajax call to ASPX page to get DIV ID innerText value

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net, get

Hey all I am trying to figure out how to go about getting the value from a DIV inside an ASPX page. Currently the code below is returning the full html body (as it would look if you right-click on the aspx page and looked at the source code).

However, everytime i check out the returned html it doesnt seem to have the ID name that I gave to the DIV in Visual studio.

The aspx code:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="excelData.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="returnableData" runat="server"></div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The **returnableData** is the div id I am wanting to fetch the **innertext** of.

The JS code is:

```
$.ajax({
    type    : 'GET',
    async   : false,
    url     : "excelData.aspx",
    dataType: 'html',
    data    : {range: "A6"},
    success : function (Data) {
        var theReturnedData = $response.filter('#returnableData').text();
        console.log(theReturnedData);
    },
    error   : function(Data) { 
        console.log('error'); 
    }
});
```

The error happens on the line:

```
var theReturnedData = $response.filter('#returnableData').text();
```

The source for the retuned ajax call looks like this:

```
LOG: It's one of the most important games in the world!

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>

</title></head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="excelData.aspx?range=A6" id="form1">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwULLTE2MTY2ODcyMjlkZHTGmy0pCtoTD5qZ7o7ahrANn9wvWGc9h813Indizofg" />
</div>

    <div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see by the code above, it does see the value it should have in the div:

```
LOG: It's one of the most important games in the world!
```

But its not inside the div... and the div itself **doesn't** even have the **ID** to it???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET is clobbering your ID based on the control structure.  You need to change the control's ClientIDMode to Static.

```
   <div id="returnableData" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"></div>
```